# Who calls the private method during unwinding in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

For implementing **unwind segue** we need make control-drag in the storyboard and
create **private** method in the destination view controller.

I don't understand : if method **is private**, how it works? Because in the implementation file of my view controller this NOT calling.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you share any of your code to illustrate your question?  It's not entirely clear what you are asking.

Comment: - (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{}

Hi, this is from "Start Developing iOS Apps Today"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When executed, your application parses the .storyboard file at first, getting to know what classes it needs to instantiate and other important information, like segue connections. Then, it creates class instances (and manages them later). Then, when requested (e.g. after a button press), it attempts to find a method `unwindToList:` in the controller instance. If there is one, it would execute. If not, an exception would be thrown.

However, that method is not exactly hidden. Basically, there is no such thing as a **private** method in Objective-C; at least not in the same way as some other languages have. Every method is accessible by the runtime. If you're interested in how Objective-C works *exactly*, take a look at these pages, for example:

[How does objective-c handle method resolution at run-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219840/how-does-objective-c-handle-method-resolution-at-run-time)

http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.ru/2010/01/understanding-objective-c-runtime.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In what cases I will use a method declaration only within ".m" file?

Comment: Actually that would be one of the tricks to imitate "private" behaviour. There is no definite guide for that. Generally you would put public APIs to .h files, while internals are kept inside.